# Simple Endpoint (WebService) in AWS

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need a simple endpoint in AWS.
Situation is:

**WebService <-> [AWS_COMPONENT] <-> DynamoDB**

So .net WebService (which isn't in AWS) needs to  access data from DynamoDB via [AWS_COMPONENT]. [AWS_COMPONENT] should get the data from the database and return it to WebService. So my question is which AWS component (solution) should I use as a [AWS_COMPONENT].

One of ideas is that I can create [AWS_COMPONENT] as a .net Web app on EC2, but isn't overkill? Is any easier or simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

The situation that you are describing fits perfectly with AWS API Gateway. There is a complete tutorial on how to make this work [on this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/)

You are right that web app on EC2 would be overkill.